# How to make text or anything move when program starts

Tags: html, jquery, css, game-development

I am currently developing a game for a class and I need my obstacles to move when the program starts so that the player doesn't have to activate the obstacles manually. I'm using jQuery 3.4.1 and I'm quite new to programming so I don't know if I can even do this I would appreciate some help on this topic I will link the fiddle I am using to create this game and give you the code for my game.

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Gamebit/96mLcfxw/20/

jQuery:

```
`document.addEventListener('keydown', function(moveKey) {
  if(moveKey.key === 'w') {
   $("#rightLeg").animate({top: "5px"})
    $("#leftLeg").animate({top: "5px"})
    $("#bidenHead").animate({top: "-150px"});
    $("#body").animate({top: "-150px"});
    $("#leftArm").animate({top: "-150px"});
    $("#rightArm").animate({top: "-150px"});
    $("#rightLeg").animate({top: "-150px"},200, function(){});
    $("#leftLeg").animate({top: "-150px"},200, function(){});
    }
    
   if(moveKey.key === 's'){
      $("#bidenHead").animate({top: "150px"});
    $("#body").animate({top: "150px"});
    $("#leftArm").animate({top: "150px"});
    $("#rightArm").animate({top: "150px"});
    $("#rightLeg").animate({top: "150px"});
    $("#leftLeg").animate({top: "150px"}); 
    }
  
    if(moveKey.key === 'a'){
    $("#bidenHead").animate({right: "790px"}, 500, function(){}); 
    $("#body").animate({right: "835px"}, 565, function(){});
    $("#leftArm").animate({right: "862px"}, 645, function(){});
    $("#rightArm").animate({right: "808px"}, 450, function(){});
    $("#rightLeg").animate({right: "800px"}, 625, function(){});
    $("#leftLeg").animate({right: "870px"}, 450, function(){}); 
     }

  if(moveKey.key === 'd') {
    $("#bidenHead").animate({right: "250px"}, 500, function(){});
    $("#body").animate({right: "295px"}, 565, function(){});
    $("#leftArm").animate({right: "322px"}, 645, function(){});
    $("#rightArm").animate({right: "267px"}, 450, function(){});
    $("#rightLeg").animate({right: "260px"}, 625, function(){});
    $("#leftLeg").animate({right: "330px"}, 450, function(){}); 
     }
  })
```

and the CSS:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 510px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.stickBody {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 556px;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.stickArmLeft {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 528px;
  margin-top: 300px;

}

.stickArmRight {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 585px;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.stickLegLeft {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 522px;
  margin-top: 385px;
}

.stickLegRight {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 590px;
  margin-top: 385px;
}

p1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

p2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}

p3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 1056px;
}

p4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 370px;
  left: 1045px;
}

    
    `
```

I will give you the HTML if anybody needs it but I felt like this was getting kinda long so just request it if you need it and I will supply it.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? You have long `animate()` function

Comment: I have obstacles that won't move unless I have a function to activate them but I can only think of using key down or other similar functions though which would require manual input. Something I don't want what I want is for them to move automatically when the program starts and I don't know how to do that I have already consulted the rest of stack overflow and the internet but I can't find anybody with a similar question so here I am now.

Comment: What are the obstacles?

Comment: text inside of a div

Comment: check the fiddle if you want to see the whole game